# MySQL: unique data for 2 fields

Tags: mysql

It is not so simple as it is written in the title.

I have a table, for binding user accounts together.

For example: a person signs up via standard site functionality. On the next day he signs up via the Facebook account.

I have `user_user` table with `a_user_id`, `b_user_id` fields. These fields are foreign keys to the standard user table.
I make unique key for 2 fields.

But. How to avoid the situation like this one:

```
a_user_id: 1
b_user_id : 2
```

and the next row:

```
a_user_id: 2
b_user_id : 1
```

Both rows mean the same. Can MySQL handle this?
Are there any better approaches for this case?

Comment: This is pretty easy in other DBMS, but I don't think you can efficiently ensure this on the database level with MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce the constraint `a_user_id < b_user_id`. Honestly said, I till now always held this constraint on the programming side, This prevents cycles: self references and a-b-a.

First one would need to normalize the table, probably using a temporary table in MySQL.

---

***Normalisation of the old table:***

Assuming a table `u2(a_user_id NOT NULL, b_user_id NOT NULL)`:

```
DELETE FROM u2
WHERE a_user_id = b_user_id;

ALTER TABLE u2 ADD COLUMN other ...;

UPDATE u2
SET
    other = a_user_id,
    a_user_id = b_user_id,
    b_user_id = other
WHERE
    a_user_id > b_user_id;

ALTER TABLE u2 REMOVE COLUMN other;
```

*(Unchecked syntax)*

Comment: You can't create such a constraint in MySQL (it does not support check constraint) the only way to ensure this with the limited capabilities of MySQL is to write a trigger.

Comment: Thank you very much for the very interesting aproach.
Could you povide the example of the code of altering the table?

Yes, I believe this is better to do on the application side, still am looking for a better one-place-to-handle way.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, though I would prefer a stored procedure to insert, link two user ids.

Comment: Added a normalisation (backup!).

Comment: Wow! The code you have added above looks cool. Yes, SP - is the good thing here. Thank you very much indeed!